# Laravel - Form::select show name as Option Value

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a database of Leagues and I need to have a drop down list inside a form of the different leagues...

I have got this working but the Option Value is displaying as the ID number and I need it to display as the league_name field...

Controller

```
public function getEdit($id = null)
{

    try {
        // Get the group information
        $tip = Tips::find($id);

        $league = Leagues::lists('league_name', 'id');

    } catch (TipNotFoundException $e) {
        // Redirect to the groups management page
        return Redirect::route('tips')->with('error', Lang::get('tips/message.group_not_found', compact('id')));
    }

    // Show the page
    return View('admin/tips/edit', compact('tip','league'));
}
```

View Blade

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="league" class="col-sm-3 control-label">League</label>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
      {!! Form::select('league', $league, Input::old('league'), ['class' => 'form-control required', 'id' => 'league', 'placeholder' => 'Select League']) !!}
   </div>
</div>
```

It is outputting as...

```
<select class="form-control required" id="league" name="league">
 <option selected="selected" value="">Select League</option>
 <option value="1">FIFA World Cup</option>
 <option value="2">FIFA Women's World Cup</option>
 <option value="3">FIFA Confederations Cup</option>
 <option value="4">Summer Olympic Games (FIFA unofficial)</option>
```

I want it to output as...

```
<select class="form-control required" id="league" name="league">
 <option selected="selected" value="">Select League</option>
 <option value="FIFA World Cup">FIFA World Cup</option>
 <option value="FIFA Women's World Cup">FIFA Women's World Cup</option>
 <option value="FIFA Confederations Cup">FIFA Confederations Cup</option>
 <option value="Summer Olympic Games (FIFA unofficial)">Summer Olympic Games (FIFA unofficial)</option>
```

Comment: `$league = Leagues::lists('league_name', 'league_name');`

Comment: thanks, slightly unrelated but any idea how to retrieve the value of this field if it already has data in it...

Comment: You mean as if it'd loaded from the database or somewhere and you wanted to show that instead of "Select League"? If so, use `Input::old('league', $value_if_old_isnt_set)`. That way it will use the db value, then if the form is submit and repopulated it'll use the value from the previous submission.

Answer (score 1):

The `lists` method builds an array with the keys and values specified.

```
array lists ( string $values_column [, string $keys_column = null ] );
```

In your example you're explicitly setting the keys as the id column of each row which is why you're getting numeric values.

Simply changing the call to `lists` to use `league_name` as both the key and the value will give you the result you want.

```
$league = Leagues::lists('league_name', 'league_name');
```

With regards to your comment/question about retrieving an existing selection for this field:

Utilising the second parameter of `Input::old()` (or it's shorter form helper `old()` you can specify a value if previously submit data doesn't exist.

```
old('league', $value_if_old_isnt_set);
```

This will preselect the field with `$value_if_old_isnt_set` on page load, then subsequently populate it with the value submit with the form.

*Answered in the comments but put here so it can be accepted and it'll disappear from the unanswered lists*

Comment: It is working apart from the Input:old() part, where does this code go ? Inside the Controller or View ?

Comment: You're already using it in your view. You just need to pass another variable to your view to use as the second parameter for `Input::old()`

Comment: Sorry Ben I really can't get my head around this one...

Currently I have

{!! Form::select('league', $league, Input::old('league', 'Select'), ['class' => 'form-control required', 'id' => 'league', 'placeholder' => 'Select League']) !!}